# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to a button works on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a universal (iPhone and iPad) app sharing code.

I'm running the following on a button, it works as expected on the iPhone, but on iPad it physically moves the button to a different position on the screen before rotation. The storyboard for iPad only uses landscape mode so not sure if this is related.

```
self.sButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45.0*M_PI/180.0);
```

I've read elsewhere of people having similar problems with alignment of ui elements on iPad but these are all very old now (iOS 4). I'm using Xcode 5.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I used this code for both iphone and ipad but its working on same animation effect, but its working same animation only. I dont know whats the exact problem do you facing. Is it possible to send as sample project?, if applicable means i will help from our side

Answer (score 0):

i think i understand your question. Make sure to select or deselect "use auto layout". See example below.

"before pressed"

[image]

"auto layout selected (button pressed)"

[image]

"auto layout not selected (button pressed)"

[image]

Select or deselect auto layout can be done at the utilities view on the right.

[image]